# Jade, Gulp, looping through array to create media-query in style tag

Tags: html, css, media-queries, gulp, pug

TLDR; How do I create a loop inside a style tag in `Jade`?

I'm trying to loop through an `array` in `Jade` to create a set of 'media-queries' inside my html. The goal is to only have ONE style tag that wraps all the `media-queries`.
The page is a template, so some values will come from the page the extends the template.
**Gulp is in the title just to be thorough, but I don't think it really plays into my problem or solution

SO the idea is:
1. open style tag
2. -- for each size in [360,480,600,800,1024,2000]
3. ---- create a media query for that size
4. ------ apply that size and client name to a background image name
4. close style tag

JADE:

```
// sizes of images
- var sizes = [360,480,600,800,1024,2000]
// variable the is passed in via the page that extends the template. I defined it here just for example
- var cleanName = "client-name"
```

ATTEMPT ONE:
fails to loop through the array, but applies the client name
you also see that the Jade loop call gets passed into the HTML

```
// loop one: fails. It gets the 'cleanName' but doesn't execute the loop
style.
    - for size in sizes                 
      @media (min-width:#{size}px){
        .hero {
            background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/#{cleanName}-intro-bg-#{size}.jpg");
        }
        .hero:before {
            background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/#{cleanName}-intro-fg-#{size}.png");
        }
    }
```

HTML RESULTS:

```
<style>
  - for size in sizes                   
  @media (min-width:px){
    .hero {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-bg-.jpg");
    }
    .hero:before {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-fg-.png");
    }
  }
</style>
```

ATTEMPT TWO:
loops through the array, but it's outside the style tag, so I have a style tag for each item in the loop.

```
// loop two. This works, but it creates a new style tag for each item in `sizes`
for size in sizes
    style.
        @media (min-width:#{size}px){
            .hero {
                background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/#{cleanName}-intro-bg-#{size}.jpg");
            }
            .hero:before {
                background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/#{cleanName}-intro-fg-#{size}.png");
            }
        }
```

HTML RESULTS

```
<style>
  @media (min-width:360px){
    .hero {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-bg-360.jpg");
    }
    .hero:before {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-fg-360.png");
    }
  }

</style>
<style>
  @media (min-width:480px){
    .hero {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-bg-480.jpg");
    }
    .hero:before {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-fg-480.png");
    }
  }

</style>
<style>
  @media (min-width:600px){
    .hero {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-bg-600.jpg");
    }
    .hero:before {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-fg-600.png");
    }
  }

</style>
<style>
  @media (min-width:800px){
    .hero {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-bg-800.jpg");
    }
    .hero:before {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-fg-800.png");
    }
  }

</style>
<style>
  @media (min-width:1024px){
    .hero {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-bg-1024.jpg");
    }
    .hero:before {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-fg-1024.png");
    }
  }

</style>
<style>
  @media (min-width:2000px){
    .hero {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-bg-2000.jpg");
    }
    .hero:before {
        background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/client-name-intro-fg-2000.png");
    }
  }

</style>
```

My next attempt will be piping down the style definition, but it feels like I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Unfortunatly not in a position to help at the moment, but I'd reccommend an `each` loop for anything jade. Also glad to see somebody using jade.

Comment: `each` is netting me the same results.

Comment: Jade only support plaintext content for the style tag. See [this question (Writing dynamic CSS with Jade)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947305/writing-dynamic-css-with-jade) for more and some work arounds and solutions. You might also be able to use [Jade's filters](http://jade-lang.com/reference/filters/) to import a CSS-preprocessor file (like Stylus, Sass and less).

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it's kinda hacky - it creates 6 style tags rather than creating all the styles under one tag.

```
- var sizes = [360,480,600,800,1024,2000]
- var cleanName = "client-name"
for size in sizes      
  style.
    @media (min-width:#{size}px){
      .hero {
          background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/#{cleanName}-intro-bg-#{size}.jpg");
      }
      .hero:before {
          background-image: url("/public/img/case-study/#{cleanName}-intro-fg-#{size}.png");
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is the same as EXAMPLE TWO in the question, no?

Comment: Your best bet is to try a preprocessor, like Stylus, SCSS or LESS

Comment: It is the same, but it seems like the only way to do it with just Jade, at least for now.