# Jade How to do conditional css with variable passed from routes

Tags: express, pug, templating-engine

I'm trying to pass a variable 'weather' to my Jade template and based on if it is rainy, clear, etc the background will change.

Here is my route index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' , ip: req.ip, weather: 'rain'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the part in my index.jade file with the conditional I am trying to pass

```
//styles
    style.
      .intro {
      if weather == 'rain'
        background: url(../images/rain.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
      }
```

Here is where I just changed the background with no conditional and it worked

```
//styles
    style.
      .intro {
      background: url(../images/rain.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
      }
```

I have the latest version of jade and I made sure to indent so I'm not quite sure where my syntax is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the approach you describe. As explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949342), `style` contents are not interpreted by Pug and just kept as-is in plain text format. That means that any conditional logic needs to happen in the actual body of the page.

You could easily solve this by creating two (or more) classes, named `.rainy` and `.clear`, and define those statically in the `style` section. Then, in the body, you could dynamically add classes to the `.intro` element based on the value of `weather`.